# Partial payment refund, common approach

Tags: shopware6

My plugin implements third-party service for packaging orders. We add extra fee to the order and when pack is returned we want to trigger partial refund.
We have 2 questions about this:

1. Is it allowed for plugin that works with shippment trigger order refunds?
2. Is it possible to implement common solution for all payment methods who support refund or maybe there is some workaround?

In Shopware 6 core we have RefundPaymentHandlerInterface, but neither PayPal nor Mollie implement it, these plugins implement refund in own way.